# Why using select gives me undefined error in mongoose populate method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Mongoose Populate Method Error with Select Field: Unexplained Behavior

#### Problem Description

I am facing a perplexing issue with the Mongoose `populate` method in my Node.js application. I have a `getAllPosts` function responsible for fetching posts and populating the `author` and `category` fields. The code snippet looks like this:

```js
const getAllPosts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({}).populate({
            path: "author",
            select: "_id firstname lastname username profilePicture"
        }).populate({
            path: "category",
            select: "title slug"
        });
        
        if (!posts) {
            throw new CustomError.NotFoundError("There are no posts");
        }
        
        console.log(posts);
        
        res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({
            data: posts,
            length: posts.length,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle the error
        console.error(error);
        res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
            error: "Internal Server Error"
        });
    }
}
```

##### This is the output if I don't use fields inside select statement:

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6535054d02fa8eb454bc6c10",
            "title": "testing blog",
            "content": "content for testing blog",
            "author": {
                "viewers": [],
                "_id": "65330045556ed792d8f1786b",
                "firstname": "firstname",
                "lastname": "lastname",
                "username": "username",
                "email": "user@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$10$VLpgNp4XxhpcTtInEaRR/Oqoi06YXZuhxGHOOrABMuNl8su.jX4NK",
                "role": "user",
                "socialLinks": [],
                "posts": [
                    "6535001c0e2d7e54c9cc0113",
                    "6535054d02fa8eb454bc6c10"
                ],
                "favorites": [],
                "likes": [
                    "6535001c0e2d7e54c9cc0113"
                ],
                "followers": [],
                "following": [],
                "isEmailVerified": false,
                "accountStatus": "active",
                "registrationDate": "2023-10-20T22:33:41.979Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "fullname": "firstname lastname",
                "postCounts": 2,
                "followersCount": 0,
                "followingCount": 0,
                "id": "65330045556ed792d8f1786b"
            },
            "tags": [],
            "category": {
                "_id": "6534fff80e2d7e54c9cc0110",
                "title": "testing category",
                "slug": "category"
            },
            "likes": [],
            "comments": [],
            "isPublished": false,
            "createdAt": "2023-10-22T11:19:41.342Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "length": 1
}
```

> But the output is not returned but a error occur when I use select with properties inside populate.

```
error: cannot read properties of undefined
```

I think `posts` is undefined but when logged it on console it was printed successfully.

##### Schema of Post Model

```js
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ... other fields ...
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User", // Reference to the User model
        required: [true, "Author is required"],
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category",
        required: [true, "post category is required"],
        trim: true,
    },
    // ... other fields ...
});
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the error is from somewhere else in your code. After you do the `select` are you then trying to access one of the properties that have been excluded further down the chain. In a view perhaps?

Comment: Also, `if (!posts)` will never be reached because `find()` returns an array so if no Posts are found you need to check `if (!posts.length)` instead.

Comment: @jQueeny Actually I would like to return even if the array `length = 0`, so I am not doing `if (!posts.length)`, and I am just returning the result by an `API` call and not using it anywhere,

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood. The `if (!posts)` will never run because the results will always be an array, either 0 or more. It will never be `null`. It's only methods such as `findOne` or `findById` etc that return `null` if no matching document was found. You are using `find`. Your `if (!posts)` will never be true with `find`.

Comment: @JQueeny neglecting that condition, the same error still persists.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you do the `populate` with the `select`,  then run `console.log(posts);` do you get the documents printed in the console? I've run your code locally and it successfully returns documents when I do `console.log(posts);`.

Comment: @jQueeny, Yes the document is successfully printed as I mentioned in the question itself, but the data is not returned from the `API call` rather an error occurs.

Comment: Thank you, so yes that confirms that your `select` is working fine. Your error is further down the control flow. Is the `error: cannot read properties of undefined` in the server console or in the browser?

Comment: @jQueeny, I get the error in both the console and the Postman (I am using it for API testing).